# Как имитировать нажатие кнопки отправкой запроса?

Tags: javascript

Хочу, не нажимая кнопку, получать ответ с сервера, то есть получить ответ и использовать его для условия. Такое возможно?

Кнопка -

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="confirmButton" data-tid="0">Button</button>
```

`Onclick` присваивается к кнопке вроде как таким способом -

```
  $("#botFilter .btn").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  doFilter();
});
$("#confirmButton").on("click",function(){
  inlineAlert("","Confirming trade offer - please wait...");
  $this=$(this);
  $this.prop("disabled",true);
  var tid=$this.data("tid");
  $.ajax({
    url:"scripts/_confirm.php",
    type:"GET",
    data:{"tid":tid},
    success:function(data){
      try{
        data=JSON.parse(data);
        if(data.success){
          if(data.action=="accept"){
            inlineAlert("success",data.result);
          }else{
            inlineAlert("cross",data.result);
          }
```

В этом деле сам разбираюсь плохо, пожалуйста объясните поподробнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот интересующий Вас участок кода:

```
$this=$(#confirmButton); // селектим кнопку с id = confirmButton
var tid=$this.data("tid"); // берем значение параметра data-tid из нее

// отправляем запрос на сервер
$.ajax(
    {
        url:"scripts/_confirm.php",
        type:"GET",
        data:{"tid":tid},
        success:function(data){
            // здесь обрабатываем успешный ответ от сервера.
            // т.е. именно в этом месте Вы должны что-либо
            // делать с результатом ответа.
            // сам результат находится в переменной data
            console.log(data);
            try{
                var data = JSON.parse(data);
                if(data.success){
                    if(data.action=="accept"){
                        inlineAlert("success",data.result);
                    }else{
                        inlineAlert("cross",data.result);
                    }
                }
            }finally{

            };
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Я вот пытался делать такого же вида запрос, либо я в коде не все нашел что нужно, у меня при отправки запроса такового в консоли пишет ответ `SyntaxError: illegal character`

Comment: А хотя нет уже разобрался, почему то при нажатии на кнопку запрос отправляется к файлу `scripts/_confirm.php?tid=1253042471`, а при отправке запроса кодом отправляется просто на `scripts/_confirm.php`

Comment: SyntaxError: illegal character - это синтаксическая ошибка. где-то символ какой-то потерян. Это хорошо гуглится. попробуйте первоначально код отдебажить в консоли ( пример для chrome - https://learn.javascript.ru/debugging-chrome )

Comment: Все спасибо большое, разобрался, очень помогли!!!!!!